# dynamic async await in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await

trying to build a generic function that calls async functions dynamically.

```
//passing the controller and functionName (string) 
function asyncAwaitCaller(controller, functionName) {
    let result = await controller[functionName];
}
```

and in my controller :

```
async dummyFunction() {
     return "dummy";
}
```

but I get the following error :

```
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

Is there a way around this, because this works fine with Promises.

Comment: you have to declare a function as `async` if you implement `await`

Comment: I have. let me edit to make it clearer.

Comment: @AniruddhaGohad, what @Saikat Hajra meant is that `asyncAwaitCaller` has to be `async` in order to use `await`

Comment: `async function asyncAwaitCaller... `

Comment: The `async` decorator means "inside _this function_ I am declaring you will find an `await` and when you do, stop executing and _await_ the response."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use [`async`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) here:

```
async function asyncAwaitCaller(controller, functionName) {
    let result = await controller[functionName];
}
```

Because you cannot use await if your parent function is not `async`